# How can I specify a prepopulated value for many to many relationships in django 1.0 (flatpages)?

Tags: django, django-flatpages

Django flatpages uses a many-to-many relationship with the django Site model

```
class FlatPage(Model)
    ...
    sites = ManyToManyField(Site)
```

You must select a site when creating a new flatpage.  While I might utilize multiple sites later, right now it's unnecessary an annoying.  I want to have the current (and only) Site preselected on the add form.  I can't figure out how to make this happen.  I've made several other successful modifications to the default flatpages behavior.  But this one escapes me.

I wanted to do something like the following:

```
sites = ManyToManyField(Site, default=Site.objects.get_current)
```

But that doesn't work.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the trailing parens after get current

Site.objects.get_current()

Comment: That's not a typo.  The default option takes a callable object.  Unless I'm mistaken that means you pass the actual function and it gets called upon object creation.  FYI, I did try it with the parens when the above didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [limit_choices_to](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to) argument?

Alternatively move away from the flatpages and create your own custom pages models if you do not need to be dependent on the site framework.

Comment: limit_choices_to doesn't actually select the value in the widget

Answer (score 0):

You can extend FlatPageAdmin, exclude sites and save flatpage with your current site. Sort of:

```
class ExtendedFlatPageAdmin(FlatPageAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('url', 'title', 'content')
        }),
        ('Advanced options', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('enable_comments', 'registration_required', 'template_name')
        }),
    )

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()
        current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
        obj.sites.add(current_site)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just employed a little jquery to do this.  It's not very portable but worked for me. The select box for sites has the id "id_sites", so:

```
$('#id_sites').attr('selectedIndex',0);
```

Just selects the first option automatically.  I put this in the document load event and it works just fine.